# Redirect on Login with Hashrouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import Store from './store/configureStore'
import Register from "./view/RegisterView"
import Login from "./view/LoginView"
import Dashboard from "./view/DashboardView"

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Provider store={Store}>
            <Router basename="/">
              <div>
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}>
                  </Route>
              </div>
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have my App.js where i give my different route. When the Login is successful i want to go to my /dashboard route. (but we can access it only when we are logged in).

In my Login component i would like to change the route.

I try it to change it like that:

```
this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
```

but history is undefined.

I read some tutorial on google and they tell me that i can use:

```
onEnter={requireAuth}
```

in my /dashboard route

I don't know how i can change my route in my login component

I expect to login and to come in my /dashboard route (but only if i'm connected).

Comment: did you use BrowserRouter in index.js. Component BrowserRouter wraps the history object in the browser and passes it to down to component tree. So anywhere in the component tree we r able to use the history object.

Comment: how can i do that ? what should i do in my index.js ??

Comment: import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);